# Omitting optional attributes from generated XML document, following LINQ-to-XML philosophy

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am generating XML documents documents using LINQ to XML. I want the XML document to be minimal, i.e. seldom used properties should be omitted. Currently, I am doing it like this:

```cs
XElement element = new XElement("myelement",
        new XAttribute("property1", value1),
        new XAttribute("property2", value2));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rareValue1))
{
    element.Add(new XAttribute("rareProperty1", rareValue1));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rareValue2))
{
    element.Add(new XAttribute("rareProperty2", rareValue2));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rareValue3))
{
    element.Add(new XAttribute("rareProperty3", rareValue3));
}
```

But actually, if would like to omit the "if"-statements, because they are not very elegant and they contradict the LINQ to XML philosophy where you can easily create XML trees by nesting as described in [Creating Trees in XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387089.aspx).
So, I would like to do something like this:

```cs
XElement element = new XElement("myelement",
        new XAttribute("property1", value1),
        new XAttribute("property2", value2),
        new XAttribute("rareProperty1", string.IsNullOrEmpty(rareValue1) ? Flag.Omit : rareValue1),
        new XAttribute("rareProperty2", string.IsNullOrEmpty(rareValue2) ? Flag.Omit : rareValue1),
        new XAttribute("rareProperty3", string.IsNullOrEmpty(rareValue3) ? Flag.Omit : rareValue1),
);
```

I.e. the C# source code contains all child attributes of `myelement` inside its constructor. And `Flag.Omit` would be some way to instruct LINQ-to-XML not to generate an XML attribute.

Is this possible with standard LINQ to XML or with some generic utility function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The various ways of adding child nodes all ignore `null` values - so all you need is a helper method:

```
public static XAttribute AttributeOrNull(XName name, string value)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? null : new XAttribute(name, value);
}
```

Then:

```
XElement element = new XElement("myelement",
        new XAttribute("property1", value1),
        new XAttribute("property2", value2),
        AttributeOrNull("rareProperty1", rareValue1),
        AttributeOrNull("rareProperty2", rareValue2),
        AttributeOrNull("rareProperty3", rareValue3)
);
```

Comment: It works; thanks for the quick response. One more question, though: Is the fact that null elements are discarded specific to LINQ-to-XML or is this a C# feature? I am asking because the MSDN chapter for `XContainer.Add()` does not mention this behavior.

Comment: @fmunkert: It's a LINQ to XML feature. The C# compiler passes the `null` value to the `Add` method as normal. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943882 (linked from the docs) - "If content is null, nothing is added. When passing a collection items in the collection can be null. A null item in the collection has no effect on the tree."