# Nesting Linq in XML Literals

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

With a three-level hierarchy of classes (Person, Kid, Toy: A person has one or more kids and each kid has one or more toys), how can one export it to XML using XML Literals? I am using the following code (`p` is the Person object coming in as parameter):

```
Dim X = <Person Name=<%= p.Name %>>
  <%= From k In p.GetKids()
      Select <Kid Name=<%= k.Name %>>
      <%= From t In k.GetToys()
          Select <Toy Name=<%= k.Name %> <%= IIf(t.IsBatteryOperated(), "Batteries=""" & t.BatteriesCount & """, "") %> />
  </Kid>
</Person>
```

I'm trying two things here. For one I'm trying to nest one LINQ-2-XML in another. Second I'm trying to add an optional attribute `Batteries` that will only appear in the `<Toy>` nodes that are battery-operated. But this code doesn't compile and I  can't figure out what's wrong with it. Does anyone know how can I correct this?

### UPDATE

OK. I have partially fixed it. The following works:

```
<Person Name=<%= p.Name %>>
  <%= From k In p.GetKids()
      Select <Kid Name=<%= k.Name %>>
        <%= From t In k.GetToys()
            Select <Toy Percentage=<%= t.Name %> /> %>
      </Kid> %>
</Person>
```

The above code compiles fine, but as soon as I try to add the optional attribute, it again starts complaining. So the only problem left now is to somehow add the following expression inside the `<Toy>` node:

```
<%= IIf(t.IsBatteryOperated(), "Batteries=""" & t.BatteriesCount & """, "") %>
```

### UPDATE 2

See my answer below.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Not sure if I get what u mean but if u r referring to parameter `p`, I don't think that can be the problem here.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Unlike *common* literals, XML Literals in VB.NET can contain variables and expressions that evaluate at run-time. Don't get confused by their name.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that was even possible with XML literals.  I thought it was just that, a literal as in a literal string.

Comment: Now that I understand your problem now, I don't think what you're asking for is actually possible.  Just like it's not possible to optionally define a property of an anonymous object.

Comment: Hmm... I probably see what u mean. Let's take another route then. Can I embed an `XElement` within a linq-2-xml statement, adding attributes using `if-else` instead?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out finally with the help of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590554/omitting-optional-attributes-from-generated-xml-document-following-linq-to-xml). For anyone else looking for it, you just need to create an `XElement` through projection within the inner linq-2-xml call:

```
<Person Name=<%= p.Name %>>
  <%= From k In p.GetKids()
      Select <Kid Name=<%= k.Name %>>
        <%= From t In k.GetToys()
            Select New XElement("Toy",
                       New XAttribute("Name", t.Name),
                       AttributeOrNull("Batteries", If(t.IsBatteryOperated(), Nothing, t.BatteriesCount))) %>
      </Kid> %>
</Person>
```

Where `AttributeOrNull()` is a helper function defined below:

```
Public Shared Function AttributeOrNull(name As XName, value As String) As XAttribute
    Return If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value), Nothing, New XAttribute(name, value))
End Function
```

### UPDATE

For sake of completeness, do check out Jeff's answer below. The above code can be made smaller/nicer by using declarative syntax, as mentioned in his answer.

Comment: You could simplify that a bit by inlining that function. `New XElement("Toy", New XAttribute("Name", t.Name), If(t.IsBatteryOperated(), New XAttribute("Batteries", t.BatteriesCount), Nothing))` Remember, trying to add `Nothing` to an `XElement` is a noop.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a slightly nicer syntax this way:

```
<Person Name=<%= p.Name %>>
  <%= From k In p.GetKids
      Select
        <Kid Name=<%= k.Name %>>
          <%= From t In k.GetToys
              Select 
                <Toy
                  Percentage=<%= t.Name %>
                  <%= If(t.IsBatteryOperated, New XAttribute("Batteries", t.BatteriesCount), Nothing) %>
                />
          %>
        </Kid>
  %>
</Person>
```

Comment: mmm... will that add `Batteries` as an attribute of `Toy` node?

Comment: Yes absolutely.  We're simply adding an `XAttribute` to an `XElement`. Just as if you had written it explicitly using constructors/add methods, adding objects to the body of the tag adds to the tag.  It seems to be a direct translation.

Comment: You're right. I learned something new. I thought that would either throw an exception (for trying to add an attribute where an element should have been added) or will "intelligently" translate that to an element.

Comment: That adds valuable information to the post. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

It is **my opinion** that your coding problem is caused by an XML structure that is not well thought out.  **Essential material should be put in elements.**  It looks to me that all of the data is essential.  If you adopt a structure that looks more like this,

```
<parents>
    <parent>
        <pname></pname>
        <kids>
            <kid>
                <kname></kname>
                <toys>
                    <toy>
                        <tname></tname>
                        <batteries>
                            <type>
                                <count></count>
                            </type>
                        </batteries>
                    </toy>
                </toys>
            </kid>
        </kids>
    </parent>
</parents>
```

your coding problem becomes simpler and the XML is clearer.  If the batteries element is empty or count is zero then the toy does not need batteries.

Example:

```
<parents>
    <parent>
        <pname>Joe Parent</pname>
        <kids>
            <kid>
                <kname>Sally</kname>
                <toys>
                    <toy>
                        <tname>Remote Contolled Car</tname>
                        <batteries>
                            <type>D
                                <count>2</count>
                            </type>
                            <type>AA
                                <count>4</count>
                            </type>
                        </batteries>
                    </toy>
                </toys>
            </kid>
            <kid>
                <kname>Sam</kname>
                <toys>
                    <toy>
                        <tname>Teddy Bear</tname>
                        <batteries>
                            <type>none
                                <count>0</count>
                            </type>
                        </batteries>
                    </toy>
                </toys>
            </kid>
        </kids>
    </parent>
</parents>
```

I have a XML based system with 80+ different types of tags.  Only one of them has an attribute defined which I still question if it should be a tag.